# why $n^{\log{\log{n}}}=\log{n}^{\log{n}}$?

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

I was reading the solution of one exercise on my book on algorithms.
What I need to do in short is order some function from fast to slow.
This is the link of the solution: [site](https://www.slader.com/textbook/9780262033848-introduction-to-algorithms-3rd-edition/61/problems/3/#).

At some point I get the following property:
$$n^{\log{\log{n}}}=\log{n}^{\log{n}}$$
but how do you prove that?

I've tried to use the properties of logarithm, but I wasn't able to get that result.
Can you give me some hints?

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: @Shaun introduction to algorithms 3rd edition. Chapter 3

Comment: Do you mean the one by Cormen *et al.*?

Comment: Use $$a^{log(b)}=b^{log(a)}$$

Comment: More generally, $$n^{\log m}=m^{\log n}$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, do you mean $m$ and $n$ are more generally used than $a$ and $b$? :P

Comment: @malloc Didn’t see your comment when I wrote my comment..

Comment: @Thomad Andrews yes thank you, that was helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$n^{\log{\log{n}}} = n^{(\log{\log{n}})/(\log{n})(\log n)} = n^{(\log_n \log n)(\log{n})} = \left(n^{\log_n \log n}\right)^{\log{n}} = (\log n)^{\log{n}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$x = \log n^{\log n}.$$ Then, $$ e^{\log x} = e^{\log\log n^{\log n}} = e^{\log n\log\log n} = n^{\log\log n}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$n^{\ln x}=x^x, x=\ln n$$

$$\implies \ln n^{\ln x}=\ln x^x$$

$$\implies \ln x \ln n=x \ln x$$

$$\implies x=\ln n$$

**Reverse the steps and generate the formula.**